# if isset, is there a better way?

Tags: forms, entities

Currently I'm retrieving values from entityform_wrapper and checking if the field exists (fields aren't required and fail if don't exist)

Is there a better way than going through each field like this?

```
if (isset()) {
   $edu_completed = $entityform_wrapper->field_education_completed->value();
}
if (isset()) {
   $edu_hs_name = $entityform_wrapper->field_high_school_info->field_edu_hs_name->value();
}
if (isset()) {
   $edu_hs_city = $entityform_wrapper->field_high_school_info->field_edu_hs_city->value();
}
```

Comment: Define 'better'...Shorter? More memory efficient? More adherence to a particular set of coding standards? By the way, you're using `isset()` very wrongly there, I'm surprised that works at all

Comment: Usually, with variables, you should do if(isset($var) && $var)... Like Clive said, the way you are using it now is not right. isset() should be passed a variable that it will check.

Answer (score 0):

I use a function I've written called ifset for this purpose:

```
function ifset(&$var, $prefix='', $suffix='', $else = '') {
    return isset($var) && $var ? $prefix.$var.$suffix : $else;
}
```

It can simply be used like:

```
$foo = 'test';
echo ifset($foo); // produces test
echo ifset($bar); // produces an empty string
```

Or you can supply a suffix, prefix or else values:

```
$foo = 'test';
echo ifset($foo, 'before ', ' after', 'foobar'); // produces before test after
echo ifset($bar, 'before ', ' after', 'foobar'); // produces foobar
```

So, in your instance you could write:

```
$edu_completed = ifset($entityform_wrapper->field_education_completed->value());
```

This is slightly different to your code a `$edu_completed` will be an empty string instead of not being set at all.

Comment: That will still throw an exception if field_education_completed is anything other than a metadata wrapper though...

Comment: Arr, I see, because of the ->value() bit on the end. I usually reference the values directly so don't have this problem.

Comment: Yeah, still haven't found the best way to do this (I'm sure it's been asked before actually). The closest I can get is `method_exists()`, but it doesn't lead to very pretty code